# 32 bit Linux clock() overflow

Tags: c++, linux, time, clock

I need to measure, in C++ on Linux (and other Unix-like systems), the CPU (not wall clock) time taken by a long computation, so I'm using clock(). Problem: on 32 bit systems, this wraps around after about 2000 or 4000 seconds.

What's the recommended workaround for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to use `getrusage` which fills the following struct:

```
struct rusage {
    struct timeval ru_utime; /* user time used */
    struct timeval ru_stime; /* system time used */
    ...
};
```

For completion, `struct timeval`:

```
struct timeval {
    time_t      tv_sec;     /* seconds */
    suseconds_t tv_usec;    /* microseconds */
};
```

As always, consult the manpage for details (`man getrusage`)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the precision provided by `clock()`? If not, you can use `time()` twice and take the difference:

```
time_t start, end;
double diff;

time(&start);
// Do your stuff...
time(&end);
diff = difftime(end, start);
```

**EDIT:** `time()` measures the real time (not CPU time) as litb pointed out in his comment, but so does `clock()`. If you want to measure CPU time, you should follow litb's advice and use `getrusage()`.

Comment: isn't time measuring wall-clock-time? i.e it won't be less if your program uses less cpu. it's measuring real seconds from 1970.

Comment: well as no-one seem to correct you, i'll do again: clock is not wall-clock time. it returns "an approximation of processor time used by the program".

Answer (score 1):

Another possible method is to use gettimeofday() twice as it returns ms accuracy.

Answer (score -1):

Get the time on a recurring basis and also increment a multiplier variable int every time it rolls over?